# Has PhpStorm 2021.1 Laravel 8 / Livewire support?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-livewire

In PhpStorm 2021.1 using Laravel 8 / Livewire code like

```
@livewire('common.badged-button', ['icon' => 'phone', 'label' => $item->phone])
```

is not supported in Blade files anyway.

I searched in plugins with “livewire” key and did not find anything. Has it anything?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would need **Laravel Idea** plugin for that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea . It's a PAID plugin, but it worth the money for Laravel devs -- it's under active development, offers a lot of help for code completion/more than default Laravel plugin (that rarely sees changes these days).

Comment: PLease point at price and where I can buy this plugin?

Comment: Have you checked the link? The big blue "Buy" button there and a separate "Pricing" tab (Overview, Versions, **Pricing**, Reviews)? The purchase will be made via your JetBrains account / JetBrains Marketplace. Do a 30-days trial first to ensure that it does what you need (in case if it's not good enough for your needs).

Answer (score 1):

You Can add your Directive Like This:

1. File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Blade
2. Uncheck use **default settings**
3. Directives > **+**
4. **Name** livewire
5. **Prefix** <?php '', [
6. **Suffix** ])?>

this solution founded here -> https://gist.github.com/ciamarro/75c415e34a77ec02c17d1a20b8ea3f17

Answer (score -1):

1- File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Blade
2- Uncheck use default settings
3- Directives > +
4- Name livewire
5- Prefix

Comment: Write Answer But Not Complete